# Run/Debug Test in Current Context with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

In VS2010, one can Run or Debug Tests *in Current Context*.

That made it easy to click on a test I had just added or modified and run it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>) or debug it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>). (or with my gaming keyboard... <kbd>G1</kbd> ;-)

The only way I can find to run a specific test is to locate it in Test Explorer and run it from there. That requires shifting my focus away from the code I'm working on.

Is there something equivalent to *Current Context* in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: "Ctrl+R T" still works when viewing a test file. There is also a right click menu to run and debug tests in the editor. What is not working?

Comment: @ToddKing Thanks for your comment. It was helpful. However I will still miss the feature that providing a context provided. This may not be significant for greenfield or well architected projects, but it is a significant concern for legacy and large systems.

Comment: So, I have thousands of tests in my solution, and some of them can take a long time. I want to just run the tests in my current test class, nothing is available?

Comment: @McKay: I just posted a better answer than the previously accepted one.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, you're going to love the Tests /Tested By code Lens http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It turns out that one can right-click on the source code of any of:

- A specific test (`public void MyTest()`)
- A class containing tests (`public class MyTestClass`)
- A namespace containing tests (`namespace My.Project.Test`)

and get a context menu to either run or debug tests within each given scope. (Note: Text in Context Menu does not change)

This has proven the most useful method of selectively running tests for me.

Comment: this is what used to work in 2010, but doesn't work for me anymore in 2012

Comment: @McKay: Works for me... I reconfirmed before posting.

Comment: What if you have two classes in one file? Or two namespaces in one file? Or methods that are inherited in another class in a different file. My experience shows that in 2012, there is context for tests, and files, nothing else. Namespaces and classes don't work.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771763/cannot-run-tests-in-current-context-for-class#details

Comment: @McKay: Well, I follow the most common (I think) approach of one file per class (or partial class part) and it works as I described.  I have not tested this with multiple classes and/or namespaces in a single file.

Comment: Yeah, it works most of the time, but I have inherited tests, which are causing me grief in 2012. I tested the boundaries with multiple classes per file and file per class to find the actual cases where it works.

Comment: +1 for "(Note: Text in Context Menu does not change)". This unfortunate design decision in VS effectively hid this awesome functionality.

Comment: Can't see it in VS2017

Comment: When I create a new unit test project in VS2017 and right-click on the namespace `UnitTestProject1`, the class `UnitTest1`, or `TestMethod1()` (created by the project template), I see the options in the middle of the context menu.

Answer (score 5):

I was just looking for this myself and happen to come across this tidbit.

If you right click inside the test you want to debug in the current context and select run tests or debug tests it will only run that one.

If may appear that all the other tests in that file fail according to the test explorer, but it should work.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745762/cant-run-or-debug-tests-in-current-context

Answer (score 5):

The way I've found to do this is to search for

```
FullName:"<your namespace>"
```

in the Test Explorer, then select all and run selected tests.

Answer (score 2):

If the selected test is a private method, the test suite will disregard it and run all the tests in that class. In order to run the test in context, it has to be declared as public.

Answer (score 1):

Vs2012 has traits which can be used to group tests. May get you some of the way there

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1-using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer.aspx